# Change colors of element with click event handler

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the boxes from white to red when clicked on and vice versa. The trouble has been implementing the colors for the boxes. I think I am pretty close but somewhere along the line I am missing a function or loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmousedown='event.preventDefault();'>
<head>
<title> Boxes </title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<style>

table {
 border-spacing: 6px;
 border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
 margin-top: .5in;
 margin-left: 1in;
 }

td {
 width: 40px; height: 40px; 
 border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

</style>
```

On each td I want to set the background color to white and add a click event handler to toggle the color between red and white.  When creating the event handler I want to use an anonymous function and inside the function the keyword "this" refers to the element itself, so 'this.style.backgroundColor' would be the elements background color.Here I think I am formatting the color either wrong or not calling it right. I am unsure how to use the "this: function for that.

```
<script>
function colorize(el){
  var
   r = (255, 0, 0 ),
   w = (255, 255, 255 );
   if (event.onmousedown) {
    r.style.backgroundColor = "255, 0, 0" ;
   } else {
    w.style.backgroundColor = "255, 255, 255";
   }
   }

</script>
</head>
<body onload='maketable();'>
<table>
<tbody id='tb'>

<script type="text/javascript">

var rows = 16;
var cols = 16;
var table = document.createElement("table");

 table.id = "tb";

 for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");

 table.appendChild(row);

 for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");

 cell.addEventListener("onmousedown", colorize);
  row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(table);

 </script>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Where is your `maketable` function?

Comment: I am unsure how to use the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `row` as `var row = 16;` then in your loop, redefined it as `var row = document.createElement("tr");`

Change `var row = 16;` to `var rows = 16;` and then when you loop to create the rows, change `for (var r = 0; r < row; r++) {` to `for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {`

Re: your click handler, "onmousedown" isn't an event name - `mousedown` is the event name, so update your `addEventHandler` to reference that - `cell.addEventListener("mousedown", colorize);`

Then you can reference the `event.target` in the function to get the element that was clicked on, and you can toggle a simple class to toggle the color.

```
function colorize(e){
  e.target.classList.toggle('red');
}
```

Then add `background: white` to the CSS for `td` and add a new class called `.red`

```
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

All together...

```js
function colorize(e){
  e.target.classList.toggle('red');
}

function maketable() {
  var rows = 16;
  var cols = 16;
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  table.id = "tb";

  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    table.appendChild(row);

    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.addEventListener("mousedown", colorize);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
table {
 border-spacing: 6px;
 border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
 margin-top: .5in;
 margin-left: 1in;
 }

td {
 width: 40px; height: 40px; 
 border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
 }
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body onload='maketable();'>
```

Comment: Good catch! Thanks! that fixed the number of rows!

Comment: @HTMLnoob oh sorry there was more to your question... just a sec :)

Comment: looks like i was indeed missing a function for the color along with some minor css.

Answer (score 1):

```
init:()=>{
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    for(var i=0; i < 16; i++){
        //ROWS
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.addEventListener("mousedown",colorize); //WHATEVER EVENT YOU WANT
        //CELLS
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        //APPENDING
        row.appendChild(cell);
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    //RENDER ON PAGE
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}
//DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

Comment: I would of put the exact same thing for the `colorize()` function that @Michael Coker had with the `e.target` and then `.toggle()` the class.

Comment: nice answer! Your comments help a lot!

Comment: @HTMLnoob awesome glad I could help!